# How to get efficiently google user personal data and access token

Tags: google-oauth, google-identity

I'm trying to intagrate my Vue.js (v.2.6.11) application with the Google Identity Provider according to the recent recommendations (usage of [Google Indetity Services For Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview)). The goal is to once the user is correctly authorised, get her/his personal details (e.g. `family_name`, `given_name`) and the access token.

Currently once the registration page is loaded I trigger two methods `window.google.accounts.id.initialize` (to initialize) and `window.google.accounts.id.renderButton` (to render the Google log-in button). Once the button is properly rendered and clicked by the user, in the callback of the `initialize` method I'm getting the id token which can be parsed to get the user personal details. Once the details are parsed I'm invoking `window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient` and `requestAccessToken` what gives me at the end the access token.

The problem with this approach is that I'm getting the log-in popups twice - once the log-in button is clicked and once the `requestAccessToken` method is called.

Is there a way to improve this flow and get only one log-in popup with all the necessary details (user personal data + access token) once the user is logged in?